# Can I use a PWM motor regulator to control a LED string?

Tags: electrical-engineering, power, power-electronics, power-transmission, lighting

I recently bought some LED Christmas lights, but they are too bright. So I was thinking that maybe I could regulate the output by using a PWM regulator? My LED lights have an output of 30V from the transformer. After some googling, I found this PWM motor regulator (just an example):

https://www.banggood.com/DC-5V-To-35V-5A-Mini-Motor-PWM-Speed-Controller-Ultra-Small-LED-Dimmer-Speed-Switch-Governor-p-1308361.html

Another possibility could be using a potentiometer:

https://www.ebay.com/itm/284233393932?hash=item422da1670c:g:P58AAOSwiQ9ZShk4

Could I connect one of these *between the transformer and the lights*, and thus control the light output?

Comment: Transformers only work with AC. That's a DC motor controller. Something doesn't add up. Or by transformer do you mean a wall wart? Which isn't just a transformer inside.

Comment: Please read the question. I wrote *"between the transformer and the lights"*. I want to take the DC output from the transformer and either use a potentiometer or a PWM regulator to dim the LED-string.

Comment: I did read the question. Transformers only convert AC to AC. So when you say "transformer" you mean a wall wart or AC-DC adapter which is more than just a transformer. That's a unidirectional motor driver so I see no problems.

Comment: Maybe I was imprecise. And I didn't know the expression "wall wart". Anyway, all LEDs, to my knowledge, are DC, so my "transformer" takes AC 230V input and produces 30V DC output. From what I've googled and found out on my own, my setup above sounds ok, but I'm interested in hearing other people's opinions. Maybe a potentiometer is better than a PWM circuit? Maybe I risk frying the "transformer" with a lower integral load?

Comment: I've never heard of wall warts frying from too low a load. And I think you will find more problems with the pot than the PWM circuit. I don't know how much current your LEDs pull but a typical potentiometer probably won't handle the heat unless maybe you go for a rheostat (which is a high power potentiometer). A unidirectional DC motor driver is literally just one transistor PWMing. Nothing else in there.

Comment: Oh, make sure your wall wart thing is a regular wall wart. Does it say anything on it? And not something specifically for LEDs (which would be a current source rather than a voltage source like most wall warts).

Comment: It only says that it can be used on 110-230V and the voltage, effect and ampere out. It's a LED string connected in series, with 1500 mini LEDs.

Comment: You should be good

Comment: With *either* a PWM regulator or a potensiometer? In that case, write a few words as a separate answer, and I'll mark it as the correct one.

Comment: With either. But you really should just use the PWM regulator.